# Set x-first-death-reason or custom header while rejecting message (SpringAMQP)

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-amqp

I have SpringBoot AMQP application where I have dead letter setup for a queue. Is there anyway to set custom message for x-first-death-reason while throwing `AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException`

I have this right now

```
@RabbitListener(bindings = @QueueBinding(
    value = @Queue(value = "core.queue",
                durable = "true",
                arguments = {
                    @Argument(name = "x-dead-letter-exchange", value = RabbitConfiguration.ERROR_EXCHANGE),
                    @Argument(name = "x-dead-letter-routing-key", value = RabbitConfiguration.ERROR_ROUTING_KEY)
                }
            ),
    exchange = @Exchange(value = "core.exchange"),
    key = "core.route")
)
public void errorListener(final Message message) {

    try {

        .......

    } catch (IOException e) {

        // I would like to set value for x-first-death-reason or set
        // custom header if possible.
        throw new AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No; the amqp protocol does not allow the consumer to modify a rejected message. You would have to publish to the DLQ yourself instead of having RabbitMQ route it.